# How to unpublish(remove) mobile application properly from Windows Store(2016)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

Once, i have published windows phone application and for some reason now i need to ***remove***(unpublish) from store.

From the last updated 3/1/2016 official [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/guidance-for-app-package-management#removing-an-app-from-the-store) guidance, i have done this:

Entered to my dashboard and pressed to button "***make app unavailable***".
Seems that is all okay and i get this :
[image]

Now app doesn't appear in marketplace, when you try find it from real **Device**(have tried on different Nokia Lumia's with different WP 8.1 versions and still okay), but anyway application remains on website(windows store) and i need to know,why this happens and how to remove or hide that?

PS Approximately gone 5 hours when i pressed button "***make app unavailable***" and still shows on website version. Maybe i need wait all 16 hours to see full effect?

Comment: @NasserAlNasser yes,i forgot. But anyway,you're not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have waited **two days** and now application isn't available ***via*** search on website version,but anyway, if you google name of app,still shows link and its alive!

You can enter and see all information of app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually, you should allow 16 hours in some cases.. caching stuffs :)

And FIY, you can't remove the app from your dashboard.. just in case you wondering about it.